# Android Animation with onDraw or ImageView?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, imageview, ondraw

I want to create an android game. Everytime someone touches the display the player should go up, and if he releases the player should fall.

With the help of many tutorials I made it work but now I want to animate it and I'm stuck. That means the image of the player should be changed every half a second. Additionally an animated rotation should be created when the player goes up.

However (after hours of googling) I couldnt find any helpful answer to my problem. The Android Developers site talks about creating an ImageView and a XML file. But thats where I'm stuck: I dont have an ImageView, my player (for which I used a PNG file) is simply created by the onDraw() method:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       for (Sprite s : sprites) {   
            canvas.drawBitmap(s.getGraphic(), s.getLocation().x,
                    s.getLocation().y, null);

        }
}
```

Now I wanted to ask how I should do the animation and the animated rotation. Should I start off with an ImageView or can I somehow "convert" the onDraw method to an ImageView? Or is there another way to do the animation and animated rotation without an ImageView?

Secondly, if I had to create the ImageView I don't understand how I can make the player "dynamic", i.e.: changing the position when someone touches the display.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

Ok, I created my animation.xml file in the drawable folder:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false" android:id="@+id/splashAnimation">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ship" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ship_2" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

and in my main file I added:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashAnimation);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
    ship_anim= (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
ship_anim.start();
```

However, now I get the error message: NullPointerException

Where is the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you have drawables that describe animation, you can always create xml in your drawable folder like this than add this as `imageView` to the layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img1" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img2" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img3" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mimg4" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img5" android:duration="100" />   
</animation-list>
```

The code for it would look like this:

```
myAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) findViewById(R.id.animation);
```

Add just event handler than

```
if (!isPlaying)
{
playDrawableAnimation();
    isPlaying = true;
} else
{
    faceAnimation.stop();
    isPlaying = false;

}
```